# In Acrobat Pro 2017, how do I apply highlighting to selected text, using keyboard only?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, adobe-acrobat, syntax-highlighting

In Acrobat Pro 2017, I cannot locate any keyboard shortcut for applying highlighting to text using keyboard only.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that.
Open Acrobat, go to Edit menu >> Preferences or you can do that by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to open preferences.
[image]

Under general tab, check the `Use single key accelerations to access tools` option.
Now you can use the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> keys for highlighting.

Use this key sheet for reference [Acrobat Key Sheet](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/keyboard-shortcuts.html)